# Disable DbContext.SaveChanges() from creating transactions in EntityFramework 6 - Nested Transactions unsupported with npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework

## Reasoning

I am in a somewhat ugly situation.

I have the need for a `DbTransaction`, wrapped around a "Plugin API" that potential Customers and other people have access to, allowing me to Rollback changes made to the database if something goes wrong (Aka: Exceptions happen).

I used to provide a single `DbContext` for this but that prooved challenging for more complex code, filling up the change tracker to quickly (which ment: performance drops, heavy memory usage etc.)

I switched over to a new design, allowing multiple DbContexts to run but now have the issue, that Entity Framework 6 with NPGSQL complains, the moment `DbContext.SaveChanges()` is called.

> `A transaction is already in progress; nested/concurrent transactions aren't supported.`
>
> ```
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel level)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.BeginTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
> ```

## Simplified Example Code

```
// Example. Resides in another assembly
async Task Plugin(DbConnection dbConnection)
{
    using (var cntxt = new Database.Context(dbConnection))
    {
        cntxt.LogMessages.Add("Fancy Log Message");
        await cntxtb.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
// Simplified version of what actually happens
void PluginCaller()
{
    using var dbConnection = Database.Context.Connection(usereadonly: false);
    using var dbTransaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
    Plugin(dbConnection).Wait();
}
```

## The question now is

How can i enforce a large transaction around whatever the plugins are doing to prevent a faulty plugin from corrupting the database (corrupting in this sense means: The next time the plugin runs, everything is fine but some items may be created twice now from the plugin, causing more errors)

## Note:

I already tried to use the `TransactionScope` for this but that yielded the same exception.

Comment: Is it possible to add a (optional?) `dbTransaction` object to your Plugin method? If so, you could use `cntxt.Database.UseTransaction(dbTransaction)`

Comment: Got full control abot how the plugin interface is shaped. But would like to avoid stuff like that as it is heavily dependent on users and potential errors include simply forgetting to use that. Feel free to post it as actual answer though.

Comment: This tell you everything you need to know: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can impose rules on plugin author (as opposed to working with immutable dependency), require them to acquire existing transaction, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions):

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext(conn, contextOwnsConnection: false))
{
    context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTxn);
    //...
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Perhaps even wrap it in utility function and pass it as an argument instead of `dbConnection`.

```
async Task Plugin(DbContextGetter getDbContext)
{
    using (var cntxt = getDbContext())
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

As a side note, I have suspicion that plugin — once it has access to `DbContext` or `DbConnection` — may perform raw sql command. By default, commands are wrapped in transactions, [unless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#what-ef-does-by-default) they are **disguised as queries**. Not sure if it's actually possible, but that's serious vector of attack to consider. To circumvent it, and as general ensurance, you can install [interceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception#interception-building-blocks) to catch any event where `command.DbTransaction` is missing.

Answer (score -1):

When using a transaction with EntityFramework, you have access to two methods :

`Commit()`, used to finalize the work you've done inside your transaction.

`Rollback()`, used to discard all the changes you've done inside your transaction.

If you are using a `DbContext`, you could do something like this to prevent any unhandled exception to corrupt your database, and rollback safely using the transaction :

```
using (var transaction = yourDbContext.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // Your code here...
        transaction.Commit(); // And you finalize your transaction here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Your potential error handling here
        transaction.Rollback(); // And you rollback all the changes here
    }
}
```